# IOS: Retrieve managed object on swipe to delete

Tags: ios, tableview, swipe

To sync a delete on the phone to a server, after the user swipes to delete, I would like to mark the item as deleted rather than deleting.  Then I plan to delete the item on the server and phone simultaneously.

My question is how to retrieve the managed object at the row swiped.

My code so far is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        Items *theItem = [context objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//throws error
        [self markItemDeleted: (Item *) item];
    //    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];//Line that formerly deleted the object

}
-(void) markItemDeleted: item {

   item.markDeleted = YES;
//save context
}
```

Can anyone tell me right way to get the managedobject at the row swiped?

Comment: How are you displaying the items in your table? Do you have an array of items or are you using a fetched results controller?  Either way, you should be able to get the object the same way that you do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I put the FRC results into an instance variable.  Once I did that Iwas able to retrieve it the same way as you suggested.